# Administer postgres from PGAdmin on remote mac using ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh-tunnel, ubuntu-12.04, postgresql

I've got PostgreSQL installed on a Ubuntu server and I'm trying to connect to that server using PGAdmin on a remote macbook.

I've created an ssh tunnel -

```
macbook:~postgres$ ssh -L 5423:localhost:5432 postgres@mydomain.com
```

And I can connect using psql on the macbook as expected -

```
macbook:~ me$ psql -U postgres -p 5423 -h localhost
...
postgres=#
```

In the 'New Server Registration' window on PGAdminIII I'm entering the following credentials -

```
Name - MyServer
Host - localhost
Port - 5423
Maintenance DB - postgres
Username - postgres
Password - <remote_postgres_password>
```

However the connection fails -

```
Error connecting to the server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Not sure what's going on here, these seem to be the same credentials I've used for psql.

My pg_hba.conf file only has the following lines -

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: First place I'd look is the postgres lines in _/etc/postgresql/9.X/main/pg_hba.conf_

Comment: Thanks @MarlinForbes. I've spent an hour or so playing around with pg_hba.conf to no avail. I'll update my question to include my current configuration.

Comment: Hi @AidanEwen, did you find a solution for this? We're suddenly getting this issue after having no problems before.

Answer (score 0):

Check if changing your postgres local line to trust (instead of peer) works.

Comment: Thanks Marlin, I'm trying to make my db server as secure as possible. I don't really want to start using trust authentication (particularly not on the postgres role).

Comment: Agreed, I'm suggesting trying that to see if it's the authentication that is the issue. Don't leave it like that if that's a problem. :)